# R- regex index of start postion and then add it to a string?

Tags: regex, string, r, indexing

So far i have been able to merge two files and get the following dataframe (df1):

```
ID  someLength  someLongerSeq   someSeq someMOD someValue
A   16  XCVBNMHGFDSTHJGF    NMH T3(P)   7
A   16  XCVBNMHGFDSTHJGF    NmH M3(O); S4(P); S6(P) 1
B   24  HDFGKJSDHFGKJSDFHGKLSJDF    HFGKJSDFH   S9(P)   5
C   22  QIOWEURQOIWERERQWEFFFF  RQoIWERER   Q16(D); S19(P)  7
D   19  HSEKDFGSFDKELJGFZZX KELJ    S7(P); C9(C); S10(P)    1
```

i am looking for a way to do a regex match based on "someSeq" column to look for that substring in the "someLongersSeq" column and get the start location of the match and then add that to the whole numbers that are attached to the characters such as T3(P).

```
Example:
```

For the second row `"ID:A","someSeq":"NmH"` matches starts at location 4 of the someLongerSeq (after to upper conversion of NmH). So i want to add that number 4 to someMOD fields M3(O);S4(P);S6(P) so that i get M7(O);S8(P);S10(P) and then overwrite the new value in the someMOD column.

And do that for each row. Regex is per row bases.
Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I should mention that it is hard to read your data. I slightly modify it( I remove spaces from *someMOD* column) to read them. This is not a problem since you have already your data into a data.frame. So I read the data like this :

```
dat <- read.table(text='ID  someLength  someLongerSeq   someSeq someMOD someValue
A   16  XCVBNMHGFDSTHJGF    NMH T3(P)   7
A   16  XCVBNMHGFDSTHJGF    NmH M3(O);S4(P);S6(P) 1
B   24  HDFGKJSDHFGKJSDFHGKLSJDF    HFGKJSDFH   S9(P)   5
C   22  QIOWEURQOIWERERQWEFFFF  RQoIWERER   Q16(D);S19(P)  7
D   19  HSEKDFGSFDKELJGFZZX KELJ    S7(P);C9(C);S10(P)    1',header=TRUE)
```

Then the idea is:

- to process row by row using `apply`
- use `gregexpr` to get the index of *someSeq* into *someLongerSeq*
- use `gsubfn` to add the previous index to its digit of *someMOD*

Here the whole solution:

```
library(gsubfn)
res <- t(apply(dat,1,function(x){
        idx <- gregexpr(x['someSeq'],x['someLongerSeq'],
                        ignore.case = TRUE)[[1]][1]
        x[['someMOD']] <- gsubfn("[[:digit:]]+", 
                                  function(x) as.numeric(x)+idx, 
                                  x[['someMOD']])
        x

}))


 as.data.frame(res)
  ID someLength            someLongerSeq   someSeq              someMOD someValue
1  A         16         XCVBNMHGFDSTHJGF       NMH                T8(P)         7
2  A         16         XCVBNMHGFDSTHJGF       NmH   M8(O);S9(P);S11(P)         1
3  B         24 HDFGKJSDHFGKJSDFHGKLSJDF HFGKJSDFH               S18(P)         5
4  C         22   QIOWEURQOIWERERQWEFFFF RQoIWERER        Q23(D);S26(P)         7
5  D         19      HSEKDFGSFDKELJGFZZX      KELJ S18(P);C20(C);S21(P)         1
```

Comment: Thank you for this compact R code. When i run the code my Rstudio crashes at "library(gsubfn)". I have added the proto package. I am using mac osx: The message is to open "rsession" you need x11 forwarding

Comment: It works now. I had to install X11 on mac. My question is how do you get to learn all these efficient functions and packages. Is there a book or a good reference website for this. Thank you again @agstudy

Comment: @Rnd Interesting ,one should install X11 on mac! R is an amazing language even if there is a certain learning curve. Personally, I tried to answer some questions (already resolved) in SO.